What are the original and derived senses of "sound off"?
Merriam Webster says:

sound off
intransitive verb

: to play three chords before and after marching up and down a line of troops during a ceremonial parade or formal guard mount
: to count cadence while marching
a
: to speak up in a loud voice
b
: to voice one's opinions freely and vigorously


I guess that sense 1 is the original sense? Why is it called "sound off"? Does "sound off" literally mean turning sounds off?
How is sense 3 derived from the original meaning?

You are imposing an anachronistic meaning on off.  Have you looked up off in a very good dictionary like the full OED?  Etymological questions where the questioner hasn't consulted a proper authoritative source are poor questions.

I’m voting to close this question because questions about etymology that haven't consulted a proper etymological dictionary don't satisfy the site's requirement to do basic research first.

I see no reason to suppose the military drill sense is the "original" sense. 1 and 2 are similar to count off, whereas 3a and 3b are obviously similar to mouth off

@FumbleFingers - in older material (pre-1900-1914 perhaps?) you come across British soldiers being 'told off' (instructed) to do things - 'You, you, you and you!' I suppose.

In AmE, to tell someone off is to reprimand or scold them.  off combines with a number of verbs phrasally.  At the moment, I'm tired, and can't rattle them off.

@MichaelHarvey: My first "outdated usage" idea was tell off = count off, number off (Count heads. Is everyone here?). Which I can easily imagine morphing into "You three do this, you two do that,..." until there are none left.

A bit of a red herring, but see https://www.onlineathens.com/story/news/state/2012/07/06/georgia-soldier-creator-sound-cadence/15604987007/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_cadence. The phrase is surely older, but most military uses of it since 1944 are probably entangled with this one.

@TimR - all my UK life, to tell someone off (particularly a child) has been to reprimand or scold them; the other military usage is something I found in books.

@FumbleFingers - yes, you had tellers in banks, and people kept a tally of things (with a stick, I think, sometimes?)

@MichaelHarvey  In AmE, the "someone" in "to tell someone off" is rarely, if ever, a child, but perhaps one's boss, or maybe someone on city council, sometimes a peer. A teacher might be told off by parent for the way the teacher treated their child.

@TimR - Interesting. In my UK childhood, it was kids who got told off/got a telling off by parents and teachers. Later on the expression seemed to be heard much less often (maybe adults are better at misbehaving without being caught, or less supervised?). I suppose a police officer might tell an adult off for careless parking, or a manager might tell a junior off for being late, lazy, etc. A key ingredient, I think, is a difference in seniority - the teller off is in authority of some sort, and it's humiliating for the victim.

@TimR which sense of "off" in https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off applies to "sound off"?

The OED has the military band striking up (1909) and speaking loudly or forcefully (1918) meanings, but not the sense of counting cadences. Etymonline has nothing. So a full etymology is not trivial to find.

Although Merriam-Webster suggests "off" can be used as an intensifier (finish off, drink off) so maybe that's what's happening here. And "sound off!" is better for shouting than "sound!" Particularly in the standard cadences of a drill instructor.

@StuartF - in the UK, 'sound off' is often used to mean 'express opinions forcefully, esp. without being asked for them: He's always sounding off about having to pay so much in taxes

@Tim I said "the full OED".  You start asking about etymologies, you go to an authoritative work based on historical principles. You don't attempt to drive a nail with a teacup.  Such questions are better suited to english.stackexchange.com in any case.

There's a military tradition of parade accompanied by sounding off with gun and bugle (e.g. morning parade, evening retreat) and marches were often accompanied by fife and drum. In practice marching the soldiers provide the sound. The phrasal verbal form is using off as a particle with meaning. Compare: The alarm went off. The bomb went off.

You know, ELU is fond of reflexively migrating questions to here, but maybe this is one that ought to move the other way. This is not really a "learner's" topic, but a fairly arcane bit of historicity. Not undeserving of research, and I'm quite curious now, but exactly the sort of thing ELU is for.

I’m voting to close this question NOT because it is easily answered by a reference work (though the OP should have tried and described the difficulty), but because it belongs on English Language and Usage SE, as a request for a fairly challenging historical accounting of a specialized usage.

@AndyBonner Isn't this site meant for learners ?? The good thing is I also learnt something by answering it. It is not the healthy who need a doctor, but the sick.

@JamesMathai I'd like to hope that all of Stack Exchange helps people learn. This site in particular is for building up to a "fluent" use of everyday English language. many questions get sent here from English Language & Usage for being too "basic," asking something that most fluent users would know. This question isn't that basic. I don't think anyone here has a definitive answer for exactly where and when one meaning came from another; that would be some in-depth research. That's exactly the sort of thing ELU is for.

Phrasal verb - sound off.


sound off.
intransitive verb.
a : to speak up in a loud voice.
b : to voice one's opinions freely and vigorously



How is sense 3 derived from the original meaning?

The phrasal verb, sound off is a phrasal verb that consists of two words: sound and off. Separating the words and analysing their meanings is an incorrect method. Let us consider the origin of sound off.

Origin.
In the U.S. military. It was a method of taking attendance. Troops would proclaim their name or number + sound off.
Ref. https://www.forkunion.com/why-do-cadets-at-military-academies-chant-when-they-march/.

Today, "sound off" is commonly used figuratively, meaning "to speak up vociferously with one's (possibly unsolicited or unpopular) opinion."

Is this your own guesswork? It seems like a reasonable guess, but I think the OP is looking for something more official.

@AndyBonner It's what I got from Google search. I made it short. As per various sites, this is the origin of Meaning 3 asked by OP. https://www.forkunion.com/why-do-cadets-at-military-academies-chant-when-they-march/

I suggest citing those "various sites," so that it's clear that it's not speculation, and so others can evaluate the sites themselves, which may just be doing their own speculation. This question seems very easy on its surface but is really very hard, since it asks for history, and since the phrase is not all that common and is often used in ways that are not well documented.
